# Data Repitition of vector in Data frame for R language

Tags: r, dataframe

For example: Here we have the table:

Height---H_Or_L

20-------High

30-------High

5--------Low

6--------Low

We need the exact format when converted into a data frame for vectors:-

**Height = c(20, 30, 5, 6)**

**H_or_L = c("High", "Low")**

Is it possible to convert these two vectors into a data frame to produce the exact table above?

If done, **data.frame(Height, H_or_L)**, the table it produce will be:

Height---H_Or_L

20-------High

30-------Low

5--------High

6--------Low

Is there any standard method to do this? (not using loops)

Or making **H_or_L = c("High", "High", "Low", "Low")** only choice, if loops are not used?

Comment: `rep(c("High", "Low"), each = 2)` achieves the result if all you want is repeat each element twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, default vector repeating is to repeat the entire vector, not to repeat individual items.

To repeat individual items, we can make a oneliner for any required length (I have made `Height` to be 5 items long this time:

```
Height = c(20, 30, 5, 6, 7)
H_or_L = c("High", "Low")

rep(H_or_L, each = ceiling(length(Height)/length(H_or_L)))[1:length(Height)]
```

Result:

```
> rep(H_or_L, each = ceiling(length(Height)/length(H_or_L)))[1:length(Height)]
[1] "High" "High" "High" "Low"  "Low"
```